# MFC OnMouseActivate: Where is focus if you eat the mouse event?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, focus, mouseevent

Where does focus remain?
Is focus left on the window that previously held focus, or is focus in limbo, on no window?

I've noticed that when I eat a message, it appears as if nothing has focus.

I return MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT

Comment: Are you returning `MA_ACTIVATEANDEAT` or `MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT` from the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The focus can't be in limbo. Something always has to have the focus, so it will either be the window that *previously* held the focus, or the new window that is activated by the mouse event.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hae1hxka.aspx) for `CWnd::OnMouseActivate` tells us what will happen, depending on the value that you return from the function:

```
MA_ACTIVATE           Activate CWnd object
MA_NOACTIVATE         Do not activate CWnd object
MA_ACTIVATEANDEAT    Activate CWnd object and discard the mouse event
MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT  Do not activate CWnd object and discard the mouse event
```

Since you're returning `MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT`, the previously focused object will retain the focus and the mouse event will be discarded.

Comment: sorry about that delay.
It twas something I thought I did, but alas didn't.